# Is there a way to implement a completer for mathematical expressions in CLIPS?

Tags: clips

I once again turn to this community for help. As another side project of mine for learning CLIPS, I was wondering if there is a way to solve this problem. I am trying to make a program that takes as input a list of numbers and adds mathematical operators between them such that the mathematical expression is valid. For example:
Input: 5 1 6 11
Output: 5*1+6=11

To make it more interesting, I was thinking that between the last two numbers the sign "=" will always be added, but for the rest of the spaces between numbers, any of the signs +, -, / and * can be added. If there is no way for the mathematical operators to be added so as to create a valid mathematical expression the program will just output a message such as "No possible combination of mathematical operators". I appreciate all answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> 
(deffacts operators
   (operator +)
   (operator -)
   (operator *)
   (operator /))
CLIPS>    
(deftemplate completer
   (multislot numbers)
   (multislot queue)
   (multislot operators))
CLIPS>    
(deffacts test
   (completer (numbers 3 4 12))
   (completer (numbers 5 1 6 11))
   (completer (numbers 3 4 8 5 20))
   (completer (numbers 1 3 5 7)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule load
   ?f <- (completer (numbers ?n1 ?n2 $?n) (queue))
   =>
   (modify ?f (queue ?n1 ?n2 ?n)))
CLIPS>    
(defrule apply
   ?f <- (completer (queue ?n1 ?n2 $?n ?r)
                    (operators $?ops))
   (operator ?op)
   =>
   (duplicate ?f (queue (funcall ?op ?n1 ?n2) ?n ?r)
                 (operators $?ops ?op)))
CLIPS>                  
(defrule success
   (declare (salience -10))
   (completer (numbers $?n ?r) 
              (queue ?n1 ?n2&:(= ?n1 ?n2))
              (operators $?ops))
   =>
   (printout t (nth$ 1 ?n))
   (loop-for-count (?i (length$ ?ops))
      (printout t " " (nth$ ?i ?ops) " " (nth$ (+ ?i 1) ?n))) 
   (printout t " = " ?r crlf))
CLIPS>   
(defrule failure
   (declare (salience -10))
   (completer (numbers $?n) 
              (queue $?n))
   (not (completer (numbers $?n)
                   (queue ?n1 ?n2&:(= ?n1 ?n2))))
   =>
   (printout t (implode$ ?n) " : no possible combination of mathematical operators" crlf))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
3 * 4 = 12
5 * 1 + 6 = 11
5 / 1 + 6 = 11
3 + 4 + 8 + 5 = 20
3 * 4 - 8 * 5 = 20
1 3 5 7 : no possible combination of mathematical operators
CLIPS>
```

Comment: I see you're saving me again. Correct me if I'm wrong, but if I'd like the program to accept input from the keyboard, I could replace the `(deffacts test)` part with a 
(defrule input 
(printout t "Input" crlf)
=>
(assert (completer (numbers (explode$ (readline))))
)

Comment: I think I've got it. My defrule was definitely wrong, it just needed nothing before => and the printout and assert after =>. Now I'm not sure why after it prints out "Input" the cursor in my CLIPS IDE moves under the word "Input" for some reason.

Comment: The crlf (carriage return line feed) in the printout moves the cursor to the next line.

Comment: That did the trick. I didn't know the carriage return line feed wasn't necessary in printout. Thank you once again.

Comment: I think I may have found one small problem in the code you provided. It may be that it doesn't prioritize multiplication/division over addition and substraction. For example:
`CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Input:3 9 7 6 5 1 2
3 - 9 + 7 + 6 - 5 * 1 = 2
3 - 9 + 7 + 6 - 5 / 1 = 2
3 - 9 + 7 * 6 - 5 + 1 = 2
CLIPS> `
3 - 9 + 7 * 6 - 5 + 1 = 2 seems to appear because the program takes the numbers two by two and performs the operation on them, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Correct, I didn't write complete program for evaluating mathematical expressions; I just provided enough code to demonstrate how you could write one. This one just does a simple left to right evaluation of the expression. You will need to add code to handle operator precedence and parenthetical expressions.